# list.filter(!=) compiles, but doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala

The following Scala code compiles but does not do what I expected:

```
scala> List((1,1),(1,2)).filter(!=)
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2))
```

What does `!=` refer to in above code?

I know that I can write the predicate correctly as

```
scala> List((1,1),(1,2)).filter { case (a, b) => a != b }
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2))
```

but I'm curious what the first expression actually does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Scala compiler does the following expansion (you can see this yourself when running scalac with the `-Xprint:typer` flag):

```
List.apply[(Int, Int)]
      (scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](1, 1), scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](1, 2))
    .filter(((x$1: Any) => this.!=(x$1)));
```

Meaning it attempts to compare `this` agains't your tuple which is lifted to `Any`, which is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you know if it is documented anywhere?

Comment: @texasbruce Scala expands `a.map(b)` to `a.map(x => x(b))`. What happened here is that the expansion searched for `x.!=` which is defined on the root class `Any`, and that's why `this.!=` was chosen, as the `Tuple` type was inferred to be `Any`.